# Why are ModuleAttribute and ModuleDependencyAttribute not working in my WPF Prism app?

Tags: c#, wpf, module, prism, prism-6

I have two modules:

```
[Module(ModuleName = ModuleNames.Common)]
public class CommonModule: BaseModule
```

and

```
[ModuleDependency(ModuleNames.Common)]
[Module(ModuleName = ModuleNames.Branch, OnDemand = true)]
public class BranchModule : BaseModule
```

Then I register them like this, in `Bootstrapper.ConfigureModuleCatalog`:

```
ctlg.AddModule(ModuleNames.Common, typeof(CommonModule).AssemblyQualifiedName, InitializationMode.WhenAvailable);
ctlg.AddModule(typeof(BranchModule), InitializationMode.OnDemand);
```

When I inspect the module catalogue, only `CommonModule` is correctly configured, because I specify all the module attributes in `AddModule`, not because of its `[Module(ModuleName = ModuleNames.Common)]` attribute. These attributes seem to plain be ignored, because despite `BranchModule` having two attributes, but I don't supply that info in `AddModule`, in the catalogue, this module's name is its type name, and it has no dependencies.

What are these attributes for if I still have to duplicate the same info when calling `AddModule`?

Comment: RTFM: http://prismlibrary.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WPF/04-Modules/

Comment: @R.Richards The FM doesn't come close to answering my question. It shows to use attributes exactly as I have used them, but what the FM shows isn't working, hence me asking this F question after reading the FM.

Comment: Some F Code then, perhaps? https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/a60d38013c02b60807e9287db9ba7f7506af0e84/Source/Wpf/Prism.Wpf/Modularity/DirectoryModuleCatalog.Desktop.cs. Toward the bottom. You may have found this already. Maybe this is only used in this situation.

Comment: Aha! Thank you so much, @R.Richards! I am not using a `DirectoryModuleCatalog`, just a vanilla `ModuleCatalog`, and looking at that source shows the attributes aren't used at all. I'll raise this with MS.

Comment: You may just want to log an issue here: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, @R.Richards. I am even thinking of fixing it myself and putting in a pull request. I've been totally inactive in open source, except for logging VS 2017 bugs, for far too long.

Comment: I like the idea of that. I know that team would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the gracious help of R. Richards, up in the OP comments, and looking at the Prism source, I found out these attributes are only used in module discovery, particularly with `DirectoryModuleCatalog`, but I hazard a guess with other module discoveries as well. With these you have no hook to add the info carried by the attributes, but with direct module registration, in a plain `ModuleCatalog`, they've selfishly left that all up to you.